# How to plot vertical line with string in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I have two arrays, let it be called theArray1 theArray2 of N in this format:

```
5 13 20 ..
bloladsa adsad rwerds ..
```

and i want to add to my plot a vertical line at the {5,13,20,..} X values and that the string

in the same X value will be written let say on the lower part of the line (dont really care about the location)

I dont even have an idea how to do this so no code to show

edit
the vertical lines i draw with :

```
hx = graph2d.constantline(theArray1, 'LineStyle',':', 'Color',[.7 .7 .7]);
changedependvar(hx,'x');
```

now i just need to add the text at those places

Comment: Are you saying that you want to print the string `blablavla` at position `5`, `kikokiko` at position `13` and draw a vertical line at those positions?

Comment: Are you sure you have an array and not a cell?

Comment: you are right, i changed the question, thx

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
A={5, 'blablavla'; 13,'kikokiko';20,'bibobibo'}
lengthOfLine = 10;
for n=1:size(A,1)
    x = repmat(A{n,1},[1,lengthOfLine]);
    y = 1:lengthOfLine;
    plot(x,y)

    text(x(1)+0.1,y(1)+0.1,A{n,2})
    hold on
end    
hold off

% Adjust the axis so that the lines are more visible
axis([0 25 0 15])
```

[image]

---

**Details**

Loop through your items

```
for n=1:size(A,1)
```

Generate `x` and `y` values. The important thing is that `x` and `y` are of the same length. We use [repmat](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) to repeat a value e.g ten times.

```
x = repmat(A{n,1},[1,lengthOfLine]);
y = 1:lengthOfLine;
```

An example output would be

```
x = [   20   20   20   20   20   20   20   20   20   20];
y = [    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10];
```

This will draw a vertical lines and x = 20.

Plot the `x` and `y`.

```
plot(x,y)
```

Add text to the plot. The coordinates of the text will refer to the coordinate system so I add `0.1` to the first x value x(1) so that the text will appear just to the right of the line.

```
text(x(1)+0.1,y(1)+0.1,A{n,2})
hold on
```

Adjust the axis so that the lines are more visible

```
axis([0 25 0 15])
```

Comment: thx but as i added, a nicer way is to use

hx = graph2d.constantline(theArray1, 'LineStyle',':', 'Color',[.7 .7 .7]);
changedependvar(hx,'x');

and i will try the text part from your ans